# Show only latest lines in VB Label

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

**Problem**
In a VB label, if there are more lines than the fixed height can support, then the additional lines get cut off and the user only sees the first couple of lines.

I need it to be completely opposite. I want to see the latest 5 or 6 lines. What that means is that if there is more lines than the fixed height of the label can show, then instead of simply cutting them off, all the lines should move up with the latest one at the bottom. The top lines can be cut off, but the latest one needs to be in the bottom.

**Example of what I am trying to do**
If you look at a console and enter a command like `dir`, then it lists the latest directories, but you see latest read directory at the bottom. Basically, you see the latest directory it read. You only see the latest 5 or 6 directories it read instead of seeing every printed line.

Another Example: Look a textbox. If you type in more text than the height, then you see that the textbox autoscrolls with you on the text and shows the latest lines while the older ones keep moving up and eventually get cut-off until you move the scroll bar up. I need it to be exactly the same, except without scroll bars.

One more example: If you set the TextAlign property of the label to Bottom Center, then you see the text move up as you add more lines. The problem occurs when the label is filled with the lines and the text exceeds the height and gets cut off. That shouldn't happen. The text at top should get cut off, but the latest line should keep coming from the bottom.

**Solutions recommended by others**
The only solution that I have been given is to create a custom control derived from the label.

Is there any other way that this can be done?

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a button and a label on a NEW form (so as not to mess up your existing code) and copy and paste the code below and click the button repeatedly and see if this solves your issue.

obviously if it does you still have to mess with the code so it suits your particular needs.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Static TextLines As Generic.List(Of String) = Nothing
    Static SingleLineHeight As Integer = Nothing
    Static maxrows As Integer
    Static qty As Integer = Nothing
    Dim text As String = Nothing
    Dim counta As Integer = Nothing
    '
    'set MAX ROWS
    maxrows = 6
    ' Initalise
    If TextLines Is Nothing Then TextLines = New Generic.List(Of String)
    If SingleLineHeight = 0 Then
        Label1.Text = "Test Line"
        SingleLineHeight = Label1.Font.Height
        Label1.Text = ""
    End If
    '
    'process
    qty = qty + 1
    text = "Line Number " & qty
    TextLines.Add(text)
    Label1.Text = ""
    If TextLines.Count > maxrows - 1 Then TextLines.RemoveAt(0)
    For counta = 0 To TextLines.Count - 1
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & TextLines(counta) & vbCrLf
    Next

End Sub
```